# Disable Selected Checkbox in lightning:checkboxGroup

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am trying to disable conditional disable on the checkboxGroup, but couldn't find anything, there is no use of disable="true" as it disables the whole checkboxGroup. I want to disable only one, or both. Any help is appreciated. thanks

```
  <aura:attribute name="value" type="List" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[
                                                        {'label': 'Option 1', 'value': 'option1','disabled':'true'},
                                                        {'label': 'Option 2', 'value': 'option2'}
                                                        ]"/>


<div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
    <lightning:checkboxGroup name="Add" label="please select One!"
                             options="{! v.options }"
                             value="{! v.value }"
                             required="true"/>
```

Comment: Why not us lightning:input checkboxes then?

Comment: I know I can lightning:input, but using lightning:checkboxgroup is better, with no extra indentation or something.

Comment: For your use case you will be better off using lightning input components

Comment: So are you saying its not even possible to do disabling conditionally in groupCheckbox ?